# Can we use Helidon MP RestClient to make HTTP/2 requests?

Tags: helidon, helidon-webclient

We are exploring Helidon MP and would like to use it to support microservice communication using REST over HTTP/2. Would like to understand if Helidon MP supports its RestClient micro-profile to make HTTP/2 requests.

We did not find any documentation providing details for this, and so had to use custom code on the client side to perform HTTP/2 request execution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no HTTP/2 support in the Helidon MP RestClient.